# How can I arrange a group within a data frame based on year?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame ("df") which I want to order based on year for a specific group based on Ticker.

| year | Ticker | at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | FLWS | 286.127 |
| 2003 | FLWS | 214.796 |
| 2007 | FLWS | 352.507 |
| 2008 | FLWS | 371.338 |
| 2004 | FLWS | 261.552 |
| 2005 | FLWS | 251.952 |
| 2010 | FLWS | 256.086 |
| 2011 | FLWS | 256.951 |
| 2006 | FLWS | 346.634 |
| 2007 | SRCE | 4447.104 |
| 2009 | SRCE | 4542.100 |
| 2003 | SRCE | 3330.153 |
| 2010 | SRCE | 4445.281 |
| 2011 | SRCE | 4374.071 |
| 2005 | SRCE | 3511.277 |

I want to have the data frame in order of year (ascending) for each group of Ticker. I've tried using base R (`order`) and the `dplyr` package `(group_by, arrange)` but I am a complete newbie to any sort of coding so needless to say I have been struggling.

Comment: Do you mean `df %>% group_by(Ticker) %>% arrange(year, .by_group = TRUE)` or `df %>% arrange(Ticker, year)`

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for your comment! I did `df %>% arrange(Ticker, year)` and I got the results I needed.